# How to couple/connect shaft to disk?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors

I'm new to part design/mechanical engineering and I have the following question.

[image]

- Blue: steel shaft, 5/8" diameter, connected to a motor
- Green: aluminum disk, 10" diameter, 1/2" thick, 3" hole
- Goal: the shaft should rotate the disk

**The Question:** I'm wondering how can the shaft be connected to the disk?

I tried searching for bushings, various forms of couplings, etc, but couldn't find anything that can connect the two.

Does this mean I would have to machine my own coupling, and there are no standard fittings/parts that would do the job?

FYI, the project needs high torque, so I'm guessing (please correct me if I'm wrong) that a coupling needs to have a large diameter as to apply the torque at a greater distance from the center.

Comment: Have you searched on here? There was a similar question a while ago...

Comment: yes I did search here, and many other places online. Maybe I'm using the wrong search terms or something.

Comment: How high torque? Please note thet the coupling probably does not need to be much larher than shaft.

Comment: It looks like you will have to make your own coupling, even if you were lucky enough to find an off-the-shelf coupling for these dimensions it would probably be VERY heavy and expensive. Machine your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Masterdrives.com](http://www.masterdrives.com/) (.PDF - Catalog: [QD Bushings](http://www.masterdrives.com/bushings/QD%2520Bushing%2520Pages.pdf)) sells bushings of a suitable size but you may or may not want to do some machining to reduce the "E" dimension. Apparently you want bushing type SF, the E length with that taper is bound to fit. 5/8" bore size is available.

Catalog page:

[image: QD Bushings]

Another view of one of those T-bearings:

[image: QD Bushing]

Alternatively make your own or have one made for you:

[image: Homemade #1]

Another design:

[image: Homemade #2]

Comment: Thank you @Rob for the tip this is very useful! and thanks everyone for your comments.

Comment: One more thing ... QD bushings seem to have two sets of holes (threaded and non-threaded). Do you know why is that? or how is it supposed to be used? 

Also, is there a way to cap or block the shaft from sliding in/out of the bore? or is the friction grip and keylock enough to keep the shaft secured inside the bushing?

Thank you.

Comment: [Machine Screws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw#Machine_screws) have threads from head to the end but [bolts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolt_(fastener)) have a section under the head with no threading. Press-fit will keep it from sliding off or use the more expensive slit-type with the bolt that squeezes it to the shaft. Unless the motor bearings are rated for pushing and pulling it's assumed that the forces will be rotational.